# Lock request time out exceeded error

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an error when a user is trying to Register for the website my company is making. The error is "Lock request time out exceeded" . This mainly happens when the User is going through the registration process of the site.  The tables will become locked during a read or write to the server. The lock out even occurs when the new registrant tries to confirm their email. Any ideas why. If you need anymore information I will try to add it as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: where are you locking the tables? like what is your sql code to lock it?

Comment: I am not trying to lock the tables. The tables are locking when a user either tries to verify their email or complete the registration of the user. So when the system tries to run a read or write the tables lock.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood you question. Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: well mysql has the lock functionality... LOCK TABLE FOR UPDATE or whatever you want to lock it for... It looks like somewhere someone is locking the table which is why you can't make changes

Comment: As I know of right now there is no code to lock the table for an update. The code just reads or writes and for some reason the tables will just lock for no reason. When we do a normal query the information comes up no problem, but if the tables lock the first 250 entries comes up like normal, but after that the information takes like 6 mins to complete the query.

Comment: probably the issue is you are trying to do multiple things to the table at once which can cause it to lock... you may want to look into building a query executer method that executes tasks in the order that it recieved them... it would basically be a buffer to ensure that two queries aren't getting executed at the same time

Comment: I am kind of green at doing this. Can you provide any good documentation that could help in the right direction in creating such a method? Thank you.

Comment: i'm not all that good with table locking.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html --

Comment: I just learned we are using SQL and not my mySQL. Would it still be the same issue then?

Comment: I doubt it.. SQL probably has similar mechanisms when it comes to locking